# Setting bitrate for the AirPlay

Tags: objective-c, swift, avplayer, airplay

Any idea how to a bitrate for a video stream?

I can't find any documentation for describing it.

Looks like preferredPeakBitRate for an AVPlayerItem doesn't work for the AirPlay...

Even if you set a bitrate to the lowest value it looks like while airplaying it uses the highest available.